# IIS Manager not showing any of the deployed sites

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-manager

We have our as.net mvc web application website deployed under IIS , so I login to the server , then I opened the IIS manager but I could not find our web site listed there. Although under c:\wwwroot I can find the web site files and the website is running well. So can anyone advice what is causing this problem ? could it be related to permission problem ? or something else?

[image]
Thanks

Comment: if you press .Connect to a server...', and enter localhost does that show what you expect?

Comment: @ajg i tried this , but i got an error that it can not connect to server

Answer (score 4):

try execute IIS as administrator:

[image]